# PHP - Stripe Client/Customer Creation not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to create a new Stripe Client, which will then be used to create a new Customer. **But I'm getting an error when I try to create the client** *(But no error Message)*.

```
$email = "test@gmail.com"; // Only for testing: is drawn from my database above

// STRIPE STUFF //
require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');

echo "OK";

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_***');

echo "OK";

// Create the Customer
$customer = $stripe->customers->create([
    'email' => $email
]);
$customerResponse = json_decode($response->withJson(['customer' => $customer]), TRUE);

$stripeCustomerId = $customerResponse["id"];
```

The first "OK" is output, but the second is not and no further code is executed after that. So it must be because of how I create the Stripe Client, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything on Stack Overflow or in the Stripe documentation that would help me.

Comment: Maybe you're using a new API, but my code looks like `\Stripe\Customer::create([...])`

Comment: And then I just use `$customer->id`, I don't decode the JSON myself.

Comment: @Barmar `\Stripe\Customer::create([...])` appears to be the correct syntax if you are using a version older than 7.33.0 (thanks to koopajah's response). Also, $customer->id is correct. It was just a placeholder in my code because I never even got that far. Thanks

Comment: My Stripe code is pretty old. I already went through the `Stripe_Customer::create` conversion to `\Stripe\Customer::create` a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StripeClient` class was added by Stripe only a few months ago. It shipped in the version 7.33.0 of stripe-php as documented [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0). This means that if you're on an older version of their library the class won't exist.

Based on the code you shared and how it crashes after the first echo, this is likely the problem. You don't have a recent enough version of their library and your code is not handling errors safely and crashes. It's likely that if you look at the PHP error log on your system it would show an error saying the `StripeClient` class doesn't exist.

You will have to upgrade to at least the 7.33.0 version though it's best to upgrade to the latest version. If you are on a version before 7.x make sure you look at the breaking changes in version 7.x: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-guide-for-v7

Comment: I simply deleted my entire vendor folder and used composer to reinstall stripe-php, and it now works. I'm not sure how I didn't think of that sooner. Something was probably wrong with one of my other libraries.